# How can I return a subclass from a FactoryGirl factory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I have `Fruit`s that can either be `Apples` or `Oranges`. I never want to actually instantiate the `Fruit` class. I can define subclasses in factories like this:

```
# factories.rb
factory :fruit do
  juiciness 3
  ripeness 4

  factory :apple, class: Apple do
    color 'red'
  end

  factory :orange, class: Orange do
    color 'orange'
  end
end
```

I want `FactoryGirl.create_list :fruit, 10` to return a list of `Apple` and `Orange` objects, not `Fruit` objects. How can I get FactoryGirl to return randomly an `Apple` or an `Orange` when I call `FactoryGirl.create :fruit`?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you do this in a method?

```
def create_fruit_list(count=1)
  result = []
  count.times do 
    result << create([:apple, :orange].sample)
  end
  result
end
```

Comment: Thanks @SteveTurczyn - I think this is probably the closest I can get to what I want here.